# Не могу пройти авторизацию (используются сессии).

Tags: php

Разбираю пример полной системы авторизации, регистрации, смены почты, пароля и его восстановление. Код был выложен в крупном зарубежном блоге, удивлён тем фактом, что у меня не работает. Если удастся решить мою проблему, то скорее всего помощь получат еще очень многие люди с того блога. В статье было указано, что функции для генерации хеша в PHP 5.5 уже другие, но я тестировал и на новой, и на старой. Аккаунт добавляется в БД, успешно активируется после прихода письма на почту, но когда пытаюсь залогиниться, выдаёт ошибки:
[image: Ошибки]
Classs.User.php:

```
 <?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($email,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
    }

    function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {                       
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.yandex.ru";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="mail";  
        $mail->Password="pass";          
        $mail->SetFrom('name','Coding Cage');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("name","Coding Cage");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    }   
}
?>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$reg_user = new USER();

if($reg_user->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $reg_user->redirect('home.php');
}


if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $msg = "
              <div class='alert alert-error'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                    <strong>Sorry !</strong>  email allready exists , Please Try another one
              </div>
              ";
    }
    else
    {
        if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass,$code))
        {           
            $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
            $key = base64_encode($id);
            $id = $key;

            $message = "                    
                        Hello $uname,
                        <br /><br />
                        Welcome to Coding Cage!<br/>
                        To complete your registration  please , just click following link<br/>
                        <br /><br />
                        <a href='http://vh159953.eurodir.ru/test/verify.php?id=$id&code=$code'>Click HERE to Activate :)</a>
                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks,";

            $subject = "Confirm Registration";

            $reg_user->send_mail($email,$message,$subject); 
            $msg = "
                    <div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>Success!</strong>  We've sent an email to $email.
                    Please click on the confirmation link in the email to create your account. 
                    </div>
                    ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
        }       
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Signup | Coding Cage</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="login">
    <div class="container">
                <?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;  ?>
      <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" name="txtuname" required />
        <input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="txtemail" required />
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="txtpass" required />
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Up</button>
        <a href="index.php" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-large">Sign In</a>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

verify.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();

if(empty($_GET['id']) && empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $user->redirect('index.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $statusY = "Y";
    $statusN = "N";

    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
        {
            $stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE userID=:uID");
            $stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
            $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
            $stmt->execute();   

            $msg = "
                   <div class='alert alert-success'>
                   <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                      <strong>WoW !</strong>  Your Account is Now Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
                   </div>
                   ";   
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "
                   <div class='alert alert-error'>
                   <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                      <strong>sorry !</strong>  Your Account is allready Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
                   </div>
                   ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-error'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
               <strong>sorry !</strong>  No Account Found : <a href='signup.php'>Signup here</a>
               </div>
               ";
    }   
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Confirm Registration</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg; } ?>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect('home.php');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login | Coding Cage</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['inactive']))
        {
            ?>
            <div class='alert alert-error'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                <strong>Sorry!</strong> This Account is not Activated Go to your Inbox and Activate it. 
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['error']))
        {
            ?>
            <div class='alert alert-success'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                <strong>Wrong Details!</strong> 
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In.</h2><hr />
        <input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="txtemail" required />
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="txtupass" required />
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-login">Sign in</button>
        <a href="signup.php" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-large">Sign Up</a><hr />
        <a href="fpass.php">Lost your Password ? </a>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

    <head>
        <title><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Member Home</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                                <?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?> <i class="caret"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/">Coding Cage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Tutorials <b class="caret"></b>

                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
                                    <li><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PHP OOP">PHP OOP</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PDO">PHP PDO</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/jQuery">jQuery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/Bootstrap">Bootstrap</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/CRUD">CRUD</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html">Tutorial Link</a>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--/.fluid-container-->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: А путь, который прописан в session.save_path, существует и доступен для записи?

Comment: ПХП(php.ini) настроен не правильно. `session.save_path` Или не существует или не доступен для записи пользователю `www-data`. А вопрос странный вам точно написали что не так в ошибке.

Comment: извините, а можно ссылку на блог?

Comment: @Ep1demic
http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html#comment-form

Comment: @E_p
 
Вот собственно такую запись я нашел в php.ini.
[session] session.save_path = "/var/www/vh159953/data/bin-tmp"

Comment: И вы проверили сто эта папка существует и у пользователя есть права... ls -la [имя папки]

Comment: @E_p папки не было, но я её создал и дал права, всё равно не получается. И в php.ini прописывал путь другой, результат такой же. Судя по ошибке, найти не может сессию. Собственно этого файла (sess...) в конце пути я тоже не наблюдаю. Теперь понять бы, почему. Ещё я пробовал указать прямо перед использованием сессий путь через session_save_path, в этом случае у меня ошибок не выскочило, но и в зону, куда должно редиректить после авторизации - не редиректнуло, т.е. сессии нет. Пробовал еще так указать: ini_set('session.save_path', getenv(DOCUMENT_ROOT)."/var/www/vh159953/data/bin-tmp/");.

Comment: Ни у кого нет идей?)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Оказывается домашная папка (корень сервера) - это уже и есть каталог под названием "data", а я в этом корне еще создал одну "data" и уже там сделал bin-tmp.

Получалось так:
session.save_path говорил, что сессия пишется в data/bin-tmp
А у меня по факту не было этой папки, потому что путь был: data/data/bin-tmp

Кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой - внимательно посмотрите, как называется ваш домашний каталог.